# How can I reduce repetitive sources?

Tags: javascript

I made a code right this.

```js
var orgin = {
  ab: 2000,
  ab_ft: 1500,
  ab_ratio: 3.0,
  bc: 22000,
  bc_ft: 1300,
  bc_ratio: 5.0,
  cd: 22000,
  cd_ft: 1300,
  cd_ratio: 9.0,
};


var data = {};
data.a = [];
data.b = [];
data.c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(orgin).length; i++) {

  var key = Object.keys(orgin)[i];
  var value = orgin[Object.keys(orgin)[i]];

  if (key.indexOf("ab") !== -1) {
    data.a.push({
      [key]: value
    })
  }

  if (key.indexOf("bc") !== -1) {
    data.b.push({
      [key]: value
    })
  }
  if (key.indexOf("cd") !== -1) {
    data.c.push({
      [key]: value
    })
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

This code is working but I'm looking for reduce my resource

How can I reduce repetitive sources?

Answer (score 1):

You could take the first character of each key for the group and collect new object with key/value.

```js
const
    object = { ab: 2000, ab_ft: 1500, ab_ratio: 3.0, bc: 22000, bc_ft: 1300, bc_ratio: 5.0, cd: 22000, cd_ft: 1300, cd_ratio: 9.0 },
    data = Object.entries(object).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
        (result[key[0]] ??= []).push({ [key]: value });
        return result;
    }, {});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Note the  [??= nullish assigment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and the key[0] treating a string as an array

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this

```js
const orgin = { ab: 2000, ab_ft: 1500, ab_ratio: 3.0, bc: 22000, bc_ft: 1300, bc_ratio: 5.0, cd: 22000, cd_ft: 1300, cd_ratio: 9.0,};
const data = { a: [], b: [], c: [] };


Object.entries(orgin).forEach(([key,value]) => {
  data[key.slice(0, 1)].push({ [key]: value })
})


console.log(data)
```

For unknown number of key prefixes as long as they are 1 char long

```js
const orgin = { ab: 2000, ab_ft: 1500, ab_ratio: 3.0, bc: 22000, bc_ft: 1300, bc_ratio: 5.0, cd: 22000, cd_ft: 1300, cd_ratio: 9.0,};
const data = {};


Object.entries(orgin).forEach(([key,value]) => {
  const prefix = key.slice(0, 1);
  if (!data[prefix]) data[prefix] = [];
  data[prefix].push({ [key]: value })
})


console.log(data)
```